# Bootstrap 4: How to make "col" fill up to the upper columns?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i want to know if it is possible to get "col" class to fill up the space that is made by upper div's with the same class. Here is an example image that represents what i currently have with the upper module, and the bottom one is what i want to get.

***[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W27N.png)***